# doc.save() not working mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a pretty basic user model in mongoose. It looks something like this.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   email: String,
   username: String,
   message: {
      active {type: Boolean, default: false},
      text: String
   }
});
```

When a user requests a certain page, I use findOne to get data for the user

```
UserModel.findOne({username: matchLowerCase(req.session.user)}, function (err, doc)
{
    if (doc)
    {
        res.render('main', {
            username: doc.username,
            //etc
        });
    }
});
```

After the user loads the page, I want to set the "message" key to be inactive, like so.

```
doc.message = {
    active: false,
    text: ''
}
doc.markModified('message');
doc.save(function (err)
{
    console.log('save err', err);
});
```

For whatever reason, doc.save() is not updating the message key. If I modify any other field in the script, doc.save() works. What am I missing?

Comment: if you copy/pasted, you're missing the colon in `active: {`

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't that simple. I managed to fix it crudely by updating the document before I res.rendered it and saving the values I needed in another variable. Dunno why it works that way.

Comment: How about `doc.markModified("message.active")`